# Stored procedure has to many arguments specified entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with Stored Procedures mapping. I have an insert sp with 6 parameters for the insert. The entity that I insert has 8 properties where one property is the Id.

The problem is that I get this error:

> Procedure or function sp has too many arguments specified

The reason why I won't insert the last property is because this would have a default value of 0 (bit) and another system would change that bit.

When I use `NotMapped` as attribute above the property the sp is succeeding but then I'm unable to query the data out of the system.

So is there someway I could ignore a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you say you have a Stored Procedures with 6 parameters for the insert and that the entity that you are inserting has 8 properties where one property is the Id.

So that leaves you with 7 properties, right? but the Stored Procedure has 6 parameters!, so clearly the **Procedure or function sp has too many arguments specified**

Ok may be you could have a look at this http://hammadk.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/solved-procedure-xxx-has-too-many-arguments-specified-asp-net/

Comment: Well I indeed have 7 properties left but one is the Id. I think Microsoft ignores that property by default because in my table it is the `Key`. When I remove the property everything is fine. I now changed the sp that it needs the parameter but doesn't use it. So it must be that 1 one property.

Comment: @SQL.NET Warrior, Is there a mechanism to ignore unexpected parameters?

Comment: But if the value defaults to 0 & another system will change it like you said in your original post, why not just pass a value of 0 as well (the default)?